# jQuery subtracting percentage*

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic question, how do I use the subtraction with percentage? More important is there even one for that? What's the page to the jQuery subtraction? I can't seem to find one.

What I want to do is a simple task but with no knowledge about subtracting percentage I can't do it.

I use `data-val` in the `div` to store the value, like in the `HTML` i have `data-val="10"`

10 as in 10%, so how do I make the jQuery to take the 10 in the `data-val` and subtract it?

```
<td width="200">Discount:</td>
<td width="100" align="right" class="discount" data-val="10">-29,8 kr</td>
```

with the following jQuery code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#cart_review .quantity').change(function (event) {
        $quan = $(this);
        console.log($quan.parent().next()[0]);
        $quan.parent().next().find('.price').text(function () {
            return $quan.val() * parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10) + ' kr';
        });
            var total = 0;
            $('#cart_review .price').each(function(k, v){
                total += parseFloat($(v).text(), 10); 
            });

            $('.products').text(function() {
                return total + ' kr';
            });

            var shipping = 0;
            $('.shipping').text(function () {
                shipping = parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10);
                return $(this).attr('data-val' + ' kr');
            });

            $('#cart_review #total').text(total + shipping + ' kr')
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you mean _percentage_?

Comment: Yeah, pretty late over here @Barmar

Comment: Well I thought about using -10% but I don't think it will work. Sorry but yeah, I don't think it will be that easy, if so wow. @Barmar

Comment: percentage means you divide the number by 100, and then you multiply by that.

Comment: @DavidThomas But he's getting the discount from a DOM element, so he can't hard-code it.

Comment: return $(this).attr('- ' + 'data-val' + ' kr') / 100 * 10; @Barmar

Comment: @DavidThomas I put both forms in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have any arithmetic functions, you just have to use the built-in Javascript operators.

```
var discount_pct = parseInt($(".discount").data("val"), 10);
var discount = -(total * discount_pct/100); // percent means divide by 100
```

You can put the amount of discount in the discount field with:

```
$('.discount').text(-discount + ' kr');
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you already had code that was adding the discount to total. I've changed my answer so that `discount` is the negative amount to add, instead of adjusting total.

Comment: How do I get the amount of discount in the discount field? $('.discount').text(function() {
                return total = total * discount/100 + ' kr';
            }); @Barmar

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: You keep changing things. My latest code was written for your fiddle, where you display `total + discount + shipping`. But now you've changed the question and taken that out.

Comment: It's time for you to figure it out yourself. This is just arithmetic that any 10 year old should be able to do.

Comment: Even if we got on the wrong side of each other, thanks for the help man @Barmar